# Smartgit: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, git-push, smartgit

This is my first attempt using Smartgit. I'm trying to run a git push to a remote server.

On the remote server, I did it:

```
mkdir proj
cd mkdir
git init --bare
```

On my local machine, I add the origin and run push:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@domain/home/user/proj/
git push origin master
```

Works great. But when I run git push on Smartgit, this error appear:

```
Push: Could not read from remote repository:
```

**UPDATE**

I redid the steps above and change URL to user@domain:proj

Now this error appear in Smartgit:

```
Add Remote Repository: Could not read from remote repository.: Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**UPDATE II**

The only solution I found so far is to use SmartGit for Bitbucket push and run Hostagor push using command line.

I still don't know if it's a Smartgit or Hostgator problem.

**UPDATE III**

Here are some lines form log.txt:

24158 (2015-11-06 08:31:10,194) [WorkerThread-1] INFO   smartgit.executable  - Executing [M:\sites] "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" ls-remote USER@DOMAIN:proj refs/heads/*

45341 (2015-11-06 08:31:31,377) [QThreadPoolThread-6 (smartgit.aRz)] WARN       smartgit.server  - error processing command
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to DOMAIN:22

I believe the problem is that Hostgator using port 2222 and Smartgit is using port 22 to connect. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to invoke exactly the same "git push ..." command as logged to log.txt (in SmartGit's settings directory, see About dialog)?

Comment: @mstrap See the log.txt lines above. Smartgit is trying to connect using port 22 and Hostgator use port 2222.

Comment: You have added remote `ssh://user@domain/home/user/proj/` without any ports, this means port 22. How does Git currently know it should connect to port 2222? Please try to change the remote to `ssh://user@domain:2222/home/user/proj/`.

Comment: @mstrap Thanks. This fix my issue.